# Uploading images with Jodit WYSIWYG and .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap-3, wysiwyg, jodit

I'm trying to set up a Jodit WYSIWYG and I'm finding their documentation rather confusing. I'm looking at a way to upload images with Jodit and C# ASP.NET.

Comment: @stuartd I have stated in my description that I'm struggling with their documentation as this is the first time I'm coming across a WYSIWYG and it's rather difficult getting my head round it. Why are you replying with a link to their documentation?

Answer (score 4):

What you need to do is to have your server side code that can handle file upload and make sure the response format is like below:

```
{
  "success": true,
  "data": {
  "files": [
  "ionicui_challenge03.png"
],
   "baseurl": "http://localhost:62072/uploads/",
   "message": "",
   "error": "",
   "path": "http://localhost:62072/uploads/ionicui_challenge03.png"
  }
}
```

After this, you can init Jodit plugin like so:

```
var uploadOptions = {
            enableDragAndDropFileToEditor: true,
            uploader: {
                url: 'file/upload',
                isSuccess: function (resp) {
                    return resp;
                },
                process: function (resp) { 

                    console.log(JSON.stringify(resp));
                    return {
                        files: resp.data.files,
                        path: resp.data.path,
                        baseurl: resp.data.baseurl,
                        error: resp.data.error,
                        message: resp.data.message
                    }
                },
                defaultHandlerSuccess: function (data) {
                    var i, field = 'files';                      
                    if (data[field] && data[field].length) {
                        for (i = 0; i < data[field].length; i += 1) {
                            this.selection.insertImage(data.baseurl + data[field][i]);
                        }
                    }
                },
            }
        }


        var editor = new Jodit("#editor", uploadOptions);
```

There is an article with a sample source code on how this can be done [here](http://www.developerslearnit.com/2019/12/using-jodit-editor-to-build-wysiwyg-editor-with-file-upload-support-asp-net-core.html)

Comment: I'm seeking the answer to this as well. The source code you've provided doesn't really explain the `defaultHandlerSuccess` function. `this.selection.insertImage` comes back as undefined. Is there an extension that needs to be added?

Comment: No extension needed. Please follow the tutorial on the link provided.

Answer (score 0):

You're not wrong in that the documentation is confusing, and at times leaves out certain details. Here is what I did with my experience implementing Jodit editor.

First note how the backend will receive the FILES post object named `files`. My example is in PHP, @mark-adesina-omoniyi provided a [link for .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59519425/543495).

```php
if(isset($_FILES['files'])){

  // Count # of uploaded files in array
  $total = count($_FILES['files']['name']);

  // Check if any files have been selected
  if ($total > 0) {

    // Default return array
    $return_list = [];

    // Loop through files
    for ($i = 0; $i < $total; $i++) {

      // Notice how the file data has been received
      $file_data = array(
        'name' => $_FILES['files']['name'][$i],
        'tmp_name' => $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$i],
        'size' => $_FILES['files']['size'][$i],
        'type' => $_FILES['files']['type'][$i],
        'error' => $_FILES['files']['error'][$i]
      );

      // Use whatever function to upload signle file
      $file_response = handleUploadSingleFile($file_data);

      // If response is true, add to array
      if ($file_response) {
        $return_list[] = $file_response;
      }
    }

    // The return that is received on the Process function
    return array(
      'success' => true,
      'message' => "Upload completed.",
      "list" => $return_list
    );
  } else {
    return array(
      'success' => false,
      'message' => "Please select file."
    );
  }
}
```

The response doesn't necessarily have to be in any specific format. However the example that @mark-adesina-omoniyi provided is the [expected response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59519425/543495).

To implement uploading images, you need to set the `uploader` object within the options config object as follows:

```
uploader: {
  url: "/api/path/upload/", // Upload API for the backend
  format: 'json', // Response format
  data: {}, // Pass whatever post data you need here
  isSuccess: function(resp) {
    return !resp.error;
  },
  getMsg: function(resp) {
    return resp.msg.join !== undefined ? resp.msg.join(' ') : resp.msg;
  },
  baseurl: relativePathURL, // Ex: /subdir/path/to/files/
  process: function(resp) {
    // Use custom response from upload to build expected object on success
    let files = [];
    resp.list.map((file) => {
      files.push(file.name);
    });
    // Passes through to defaultHandlerSuccess as response
    return { 
      files, // {array} The names of uploaded files. Field name uploader.filesVariableName
      path: relativePathURL, // {string} Real relative path 
      baseurl: relativePathURL, // {string} Base url for filebrowser
      error: (resp.success ? 0 : 1), // {int}
      msg: resp.message // {string}
    };
  },
  error: function(e) {
    console.log(e);
  },
  defaultHandlerSuccess: function(resp) {  
    if (resp.files && resp.files.length) {
      for (let i = 0; i < resp.files.length; i++) {
        let full_file_path = resp.path + resp.files[i];
        this.selection.insertImage(full_file_path, null, 250);
      }
    }
  },
  defaultHandlerError: function (resp) {
    this.events.fire('errorPopap', [this.options.uploader.getMsg(resp)]);
  }
}
```

Notice how the `process` function handles the response from the backend and prepares the data as needed to then send to `defaultHandlerSuccess`.

Please note the `insertImage` function [requires three parameters](https://github.com/xdan/jodit/blob/master/src/modules/Selection.ts#L655):

```
url: string | HTMLImageElement,
styles: IDictionary<string> | null,
defaultWidth: number | string | null
```

Or else you may get the same error shown below:
[image]

Hope this helps along with Mark's answer.